# How to show the following set is compact?

Tags: analysis

I was wondering if someone can help me in resolving the following question.  It has to do with  showing a certain set is compact.

Let $A$ be open, and $f$ a continuous and integrable function on A. For $r > 0$, let 
$A(r) = \{x \in A : |x| \leq r, \mathrm{dist}(x, A^c) \geq 1/r\}$. Show that:

$A(r)$ is compact.

I have to show $A(r)$ is both closed and bounded.  I am struggling to do both parts.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you defined $c$. What is $A^c$? Do you mean the complement?

Comment: It seems that $f$ is not involved in the definition of your set. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, f is not involved for the question.  The question comes in two different parts.  The second part has to do with an improper integral.  c means complement.

Comment: The statement seems false to me. Indeed, the definition *via* strict inequalities makes the set $A(r)$ look open. In any event, it seems to me that the example $A=\langle-1,1\rangle$, $r=2$ makes $A(r)=\langle-1/2,1/2\rangle$.

Comment: there seems to be a mistake.  It shoudl be absolute value of x is less than or equal to r and dist(x, A^c) is greater than or equal to 1/r.

Comment: Is your underlying set $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes the underlying set is R^n

Comment: @Lubin $A(r)$ should be $[-1/2,1/2]$ in that case.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I was responding to the originally-posted question, which had strong inequalities.

Comment: @Lubin Oh, OK. My bad then. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, not at all, you came in after the curtain rose on this drama.

Comment: Also I just want to make sure, the complement of S_2 is the set of all x in A such that dist(x, A^c) is less than r.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$ The set $B_r=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:|x|\leqslant r\}$ is certainly closed and bounded.

$(2)$ The set $C_r=\{x\in\Bbb R^n: d(x,A^c)\geqslant r^{-1}\}$ is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, namely $f(x)=d(x,A^c)$, hence it is closed.

$(3)$ It follows that $B_r\cap C_r$ is closed and bounded, hence compact.

$(4)$ Observe that $C_r\subseteq A$, for $d(x,A^c)=0\implies x\in A^c$, for $A^c$ is closed. This means $B_r\cap C_r=B_r\cap C_r\cap A=A_r$; and we're done.

**ADD** Let $X$ be a metric space, let $S$ be a subset of $X$. Then $f:X\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=d(x,S)$ is continuous.

**P** Fix $s\in S$. Then we have that $d(x,y)+d(y,s)\leqslant d(x,s)$ and  $d(x,y)+d(x,s)\leqslant d(y,s)$. These give $|d(x,s)-d(y,s)|\leqslant d(x,y)$ for any $s\in S$. Taking the supremum gives that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant d(x,y)$. Thus $f$ is continuous.

Comment: how is the intersection of S_1 and S_2 bounded?  The distance function from a point to a set is know to be continuous.  That part i can prove.

Comment: @SethMai Show it is contained in a bounded set. In general: if $A$ is bounded then $A\cap B$ is bounded for any $B$, for it is contained in...?

Comment: If A is bounded, then A intersect B is bounded for any B, for it is contained in...?  A intersect B is contained in B?  It looks like the intersection of the two sets S_1 and S_2 is bounded by r and 1/r.

Comment: @SethMai But you have no information about $B$. You do have information about $A$: it is bounded. Also, you don't bound sets by numbers, but by (bounded) balls.

Comment: Since the first set is contained in the ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin, it’s bounded. By $r$   (!)

Comment: Sorry, i meant, A intersect B is contained in A.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, thank you, your solution cleared up a lot of confusion issues for me.